# How to create a defaultdict from txt files?

Tags: python, extract, defaultdict

I want to create a defaultdict using data from two txt files.

The first txt file has the following pattern (word    idf):

```
acceler             4.634728988229636 
accept              2.32949254591397 
access              3.0633909220278057 
accid               3.9512437185814275 
acclaim             4.634728988229636
```

The second file has the following pattern (textnum     word       tf)

```
0097       about        0.07894736842105263 
0097        abus        0.02631578947368421 
0098      acceler       0.02631578947368421 
0098       across       0.02631578947368421 
0099      admonish      0.02631578947368421 
0099       after        0.05263157894736842
```

The dict I want to create must have the following structure:{textnum : {word : tf*idf}}.

Can you suggest any libraries?

**EDIT**

That's my new code.

```
from collections import defaultdict
tf_idf_dict = defaultdict(dict) 

def read_in(path):
    with open(path, "r") as r:
        l = r.readlines()
        return l


def tf_idf_calc(tf_file, idf_file, d):
    tf_line = [[item for item in line.split()] for line in read_in(tf_file)]
    idf_line = [[item for item in line.split()] for line in read_in(idf_file)]
    for line in tf_line:
        for row in idf_line:
            if line[1] == row[0]:
                d[line[0]][line[1]] = float(line[2]) * float(row[1])



    return d




def nested_to_defaultdict(d): #converts the nested dictionary to defaultdict
    if not isinstance(d, dict):
        return d
    return defaultdict(lambda: 0, {key: nested_to_defaultdict(value) for key, value in d.items()})
```

I have a smaller file which works just fine. But in the large file I get the following error.

line 15, in tf_idf_calc
if line[1] == row[0]:
IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 0):

## EDITED

Edited per your comments, this does what you want.

```
from collections import defaultdict
myDict = defaultdict(dict)

class ReadTxt:
    def __init__(self, path):
          self.path = path

    def __iter__(self):
        with open(self.path,mode='r') as reader:
            for line in reader:
                    yield line

three_col_file = ReadTxt("text2.txt")
two_col_file = ReadTxt("text1.txt")  

def builder():
    for a in three_col_file:
        textnum, word, tf = a.split()
        for b in two_col_file:
            wrd, idf = b.split()
            if wrd == word:
                subDict = myDict[textnum]
                subDict[word] = float(tf) * float(idf)
            
builder()

print(dict(myDict))
```

OUTPUT:

```
{'0098': {'acceler': 0.12196655232183251}}
```

Comment: Thank you! Appreciate the help! I am trying to learn so I won't copy your code. 
The problem is I can't use zip cause I need to create a nested dic where a entry is {extnum : {word : tf*idf}} if the word in the two text files match.

I wrote my own which works more on less but can be definetely be written more efficiently (see below). Feel free to point out any way I could make it better.

Comment: This code creates nested dictionary, but grabs word from the file that has 3 columns. I did not realize you need only those words that are in both files, that should be easy to change.  I’ll update the code in a few ours for you.

Comment: Thank you very much but you don't have to... I don't wont to copy your code. The point is to learn so I am trying to write my own. Any advice on how to make my code better is welcome!

Comment: Read on default dictionary in python. I don’t think you are effectively utilizing it. The point of using defaultdict(dict) is that it will create a key that is a dictionary if it does not exist. Also it is best to return generator in Your read function like I did, it will consume less memory.

Comment: What are you trying to do here: final_dict[line[0]][line[1]]

Comment: edited version should be efficient as it uses generators. have to use a class like I did because generators get exhausted and you cannot reuse them. I know you want to learn, but that's how you learn IMHO. You can put all that code into a function that takes two path variables for the files and initializes all of that logic.

Comment: final_dict[line[0]][line[1]]  = creates an entry {textnum :{word: score}

Comment: I posted updated version that does what you want. Check it out.

Comment: I am looking now. Thanx. I posted the newer version of what I written. Any thoughts about the error? It's weird that only comes up to the larger files given the small ones are exactly the same structure -wise.

Comment: As it says index is out of range. Need debugging, I’d print output of read_in to see what looks like, then your comprehensions, that should explain why you get an error